# AngularJS ng-repeat with track by renders very slow

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web, rendering

When using `AngularJS` `ng-repeat` with `track by` in my web application, when the view is updated the old view is still displayed together with the new view during 1 second or so.

The app displays this panel of alarms (it is a home assistant app). Alarms can be enabled, disabled or removed using the icon buttons:

[image]

When the user click the icon button in the middle, the view is updated to this:

[image]

But when the view is updated, during half a second or so, it is displayed the old view and the new view together at the same time:

[image]

Is this a expected behaviout using ng-repeat with track by?. The code in my html view is:

```
...
<tr ng-repeat= "alarm in GetAlarmsController.alarms track by alarm.getId()" >
    <td class="text-right">
        <span ng-switch="alarm.isEnabled()">
            <button ng-switch-when="false" type="button" rel="tooltip" disabled class="btn btn-danger btn-icon btn-sm" >
                <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
            </button>
            <button ng-switch-when="true" type="button" rel="tooltip" disabled class="btn btn-success btn-icon btn-sm" >
                <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
            </button>
        </span>                   
    </td>
    <td class="text-right" ng-switch="alarm.isEnabled()">
        <button ng-switch-when="false"  type="button" rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon btn-sm" ng-click="GetAlarmsController.enableAlarm(true, alarm.getId())">
            <i class="fa fa-toggle-off"></i>
        </button>
        <button ng-switch-when="true"  type="button" rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-success btn-icon btn-sm" ng-click="GetAlarmsController.enableAlarm(false, alarm.getId())">
            <i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon btn-sm" ng-click="GetAlarmsController.deleteAlarm(alarm.getId())">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </button>                          
    </td>
</tr>                
...
```

And, in the JS controller:

```
...
self.getAlarms = function(){
    AlarmAPIService.getAlarms()
    .then(function(alarms) { 
        self.alarms = alarms;   
    },function() {
        self.alarms = [];
    })
}
...
const ALARMS_REFRESH_TIME_MS = 5000 ;
var refreshAlarmsInterval = $interval(self.getAlarms, ALARMS_REFRESH_TIME_MS);
...
...
self.enableAlarm = function(enable, alarmId){
    enableString = (enable ? 'enabled' : 'disabled') ;
    AlarmAPIService.enableAlarm(enable, alarmId)
    .then(function() { 
        SweetAlertService.showSuccessAlert('Alarm ' + enableString + ' with success');
    },function() {
        SweetAlertService.showErrorAlert('Alarm could not be ' + enableString);
    })
}
...
```

Though `self.alarm` is assigned to a new array of alarms objects in controller, I have checked that the `id` of this alarms objects remains the same (only changed its state, specifically the enabled state for the alarm enabled)

Comment: For each "alarm" in "GetAlarmsController.alarms track by alarm.getId()" you are calling the function getId(). If this function is doing a server request then it is normal to have this latency because it is the server response latency mostly.

Comment: Yes, AngularJS was known to be slow, mainly because of systematic two-way binding. That's why it was deprecated then abandoned, and they released Angular 2 back in 2016, with optional two-way binding (among many other things).

Comment: getId() function does not make a server request, it just return the id of the object. @JeremyThille its really so slow? I though it would be faster that dont using track by at all.. indeed I have remove the track by in the expression and the view get updated instanstly... but I need the track by for other reasons too

Comment: Is there a reason `getId()` needs to be a function? Have you tried simple referencing an `id` scalar property instead?

Comment: The only reason I make it a function is in order to encapsulate how the id is calculated/supported but I have tried to reference directly the attribute without function and I get the same unsuccessfull result.

Comment: @MABC could you create a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angularjs) reproducing the issue? I've never heard of `track by` being slower than the default object hashing used for tracking.